# upgrade to 16.04 from 14.04 computer jammed in middle

Tags: 16.04, updates

computer jammed solid half way through download. had to switch off and on. now terminal asks for my password for 14.04, but it won't accept it. so i've ended up with a computer which won't work. how do i get my computer working? i'd be happy to go back to 14.04, but how? i can't get into my computer to do anything. i'm not literate in terminal use!

Answer (score 1):

#### To regain access to your account...

You can boot into single user mode through recovery to change your user's password or in fact any users password... You can get into ***recovery mode*** by following this tutorial, [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RecoveryMode).

And then after mounting the root drive and making it read/writable, you can simply run the `passwd user_here` command to change your user's password. Alternatively, you could just create another user if your user happens to not exist...

And then if the above all runs smoothly, you should be able to reboot and enter your password!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Unfortunately, terminal kept insisting on p/w, which it wouldn't recognise. In the end I entered BIOS through F2 and loaded an old O/S, which took! I'm delighted to have my computer back on 12.04! But I lost all my files etc attached to 14.04. I won't be upgrading to 16.04 ever again!

Comment: Well, I’m glad you figured it out @brian